# Gitlab pipeline: use variable in trigger path

Tags: triggers, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-pipelines

I'm trying to develop a common gitlab pipeline that uses a matrix to trigger another pipeline but I want to add a variable in the path. What I wrote till now is:

```
variables:
  PROJECT_NAME: name
  PROJECT_HELM: helmpipe
  DEV_CUSTOMERS: cust1 cust2


deploy:dev:
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    UPSTREAM_CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA: $CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
    UPSTREAM_CI_COMMIT_BRANCH: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    UPSTREAM_CI_COMMIT_TAG: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    IMAGE_NAME: ${PROJECT_NAME}
    CUSTOMER: $CUSTOMER
  trigger: my/project/$PROJECT_HELM
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - CUSTOMER: $DEV_CUSTOMERS
  only:
    - DEV
```

But gitlab returns error saying that the triggered project can not be found. It seems that the variable $PROJECT_HELM is not converted to its real value in trigger path. How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below is the working example where the variable **ENV** is used to trigger the sit pipeline. My pipeline file is in **pipeline** folder at root level. And the file name is **sit-pipeline.yaml**

```
stages:          
  - build

variables:
  ENV: sit

sit-pipeline:
  stage: build
  trigger:
    include:
      - local: pipeline/${ENV}-pipeline.yaml
```

There could be 2 issues

1. Either you need to use ${var} syntax instead of $var syntax
   trigger: my/project/${PROJECT_HELM}
2. Or PROJECT_HELM variable should resolve to a yaml file defining the pipeline. Your variable is assigned to **helmpipe** so I think you are missing .yaml extension

Comment: I've tried:
trigger: 'my/project/${PROJECT_HELM}' 
and
trigger: 'my/platform/${PROJECT_HELM}/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml'
but they don't work because the inner pipe is not found.

Since my child pipe is in another project I tried:
trigger:
    include:
      - remote: 'https://my.gitlab-com/my/project/${PROJECT_HELM}/.gitlab-ci.yml'
This doesn't work because there is a timeout retrieving the child file (maybe auth problems?) 

Thanks

Comment: Using variable in the include might not work as include will be evaluated first. What you can try is the wild card include https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html

Comment: I tried:
trigger:
    include:
      - project: 'my/project/${PROJECT_HELM}'
      - ref: master
      - file: .gitlab-ci.yml
But the master pipe doesn't start due to

"Pipeline cannot be run.

include config must specify the file where to fetch the config from"